# What happens in each layers of a Generator in a Generative Adversarial Network?

Tags: generator, generative-adversarial-network, decoder

So I understand that in a classifying deep neural network or MLP, each nodes in earlier layers picks up rudimentary shapes and nodes in later layers detect more complex shapes by combining rudimentary shapes (in the example depicted in the image below). However, I absolutely fail to see what's happening in each layer of Generator (aka decoder) in a Generative Adversarial network. Thank you very much, your effort is much appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayIDW.png)